# Add video links to each item in listview using array of string retrived from JSON

Tags: android

I have 2 array of strings "names[z]" for video names and "links[z]" for video 
 links i had display the video names in the listview

`{"ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(DetailActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);"}`

Now I need when I click to the item in listview it send me to the video by using 
the video link.

How I can do that using links[z] by giving each item in my listview a video url?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set "setOnItemClickListener" like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, you can get position of view so you can get link 
              //links[position] 
            }
        });
```